# URL encoding yes/or no?

Tags: http, url, url-encoding

I have a restful webservice which receives some structured data which is put straight into a database.

The data is send from an OS using wget. I am just wondering whether I actually need to URL encode the data and if so why? Please note that it is no problem to do it but it might be uneccessary in this scenario.

Comment: I accepted the answer below but I am still not hundred percent sure if one needs to url encode data for a POST !!! request. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data has characters that aren't allowed in urls, you should url encode it.

The following characters are either reserved (like &) or just present the possibility of confusing code.  If your data contains these characters, urlencode it. Remember if you are using any extended ascii characters, unicode characters or non-printable characters you should url-encode your data.

- Dollar ("$")
- Ampersand ("&")
- Plus ("+")
- Comma (",")
- Forward slash/Virgule ("/")
- Colon (":")
- Semi-colon (";")
- Equals ("=")
- Question mark ("?")
- 'At' symbol ("@")
- Space
- Quotation marks
- 'Less Than' symbol ("<")
- 'Greater Than' symbol (">")
- 'Pound' character ("#")
- Percent character ("%")
- Left Curly Brace ("{")
- Right Curly Brace ("}")
- Vertical Bar/Pipe ("|")
- Backslash ("\")
- Caret ("^")
- Tilde ("~")
- Left Square Bracket ("[")
- Right Square Bracket ("]")
- Grave Accent ("`")

More info can be found here: http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/topics/urlencoding.htm

Comment: the data is posted (the web service only accepts post). so it would not use query strings so the problem does not exist or does it? sorry I am no HTTP expert.

Comment: Even though it isn't in the actual url, it is still a part of the request and I believe that url encoding is recommended.